# Python import & packages: __init__.py file not fixing ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, import, python-import, devops

So I read the [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) documentation and included __init__.py files within each package and the parent package. My directory looks like this

```
sparro
    __init__.py
    api
        __init__.py
        sparrolib.py
    schema
        __init__.py
        tsbuild.py
    scripts
        __init__.py
        scrape_descriptors.py
    utils
        __init__.py
        analytics.py
        engine.py
        utility.py
```

So I try to import my utility modules into scrape_descriptors.py with

```
from sparro.utils import utility, engine
```

It fails and gives me a **ModuleNotFoundError**. I try it with other modules and I get the same problem. What am I misunderstanding and how do I correct this?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dominictarro/Documents/Sparro/sparro/scripts/scrape_descriptors.py", line 2, in <module>
from sparro.utils import utility, engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'sparro'
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/dominictarro/Documents/Sparro/sparro/scripts/scrape_descriptors.py"]
[dir: /Users/dominictarro/Documents/Sparro/sparro/scripts]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message and traceback, How do you execute ``scrape_descriptors.py``?

Comment: Added it. Via sublime build tool

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parent directory of your package to your PYTHONPATH.

Run the following command in the sublime terminal:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/dominictarro/Documents/Sparro/`

To make it permanent look into how to set environmental variables for your system. If you are running linux or macOS then you would add the command to your .bashrc file (probably here /Users/dominictarro/.bashrc)

You could also look into how to set PYTHONPATH via sublime.

---

Alternatively you need to call the code whilst your working dir is /Users/dominictarro/Documents/Sparro/

You could do this by creating a file here (by convention called main.py) which imports and calls something in your library.

e.g.

```
from sparro.scripts.scrape_descriptors import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Obviously would need a function called run in there.

Comment: Running it within sublime so right now I guess it's the current working directory of the .py

Comment: I keep reading "don't mess with PYTHONPATH". I'm still pretty new and don't want to screw something up like that. Is there a short python script I can use to add the parent path __/Users/dominictarro/Documents/Sparro/__ to sys.path permanently?

Comment: Not that I know of. I've added another method in the answer.